# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException - Reading input - Jenkinsfile

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Below is the Jenkinsfile(scripted pipeline) code snippet to select a Git repo in stage view:

```
            userInput = input(id: 'userInput',    
                                message: 'Do you want to build?',    
                                parameters: [
                                                [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: "repo_1\nNone", name: 'Env']
                                            ]  
                            )


            if (userInput.Env == "repo_1") {
                print 'selected repo_1'
            }
```

---

requests the user to select a repository and click `Proceed`

On clicking `Proceed` button, jenkins throws error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Env for class: java.lang.String
```

Manual build is only allowed for `repo_1`

Rest of the repositories suppose to be auto-triggered

**Edit:**

After making below changes,

```
node('worker_node'){

    def userIdCause = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause')
    def manualBuild =  userIdCause.size()

    stage("Auth-build") {

            timeout(2) {
                if (manualBuild) {

                    userInput = input(id: 'userInput',    
                                    message: 'Please select the repository',    
                                    parameters: [
                                                    [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: "repo_1\nNone", name: 'Env']
                                                ]  
                                )

                    if (userInput == "None") {

                        error('Error output')
                    }
                    repositoryName = 'repo_1'
                }else if( !manualBuild && (repositoryName == 'repo_1')){

                    error('error output')
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I do not get UI after clicking `BuildNow`, I had to follow below process:

[image]

---

1) Why `userInput.Env` gives missing property exception error?

2) `input()` api takes a minute to render input wizard. Can we optimise?

Answer (score 1):

1. `No such property: Env for class: String` - i believe that `input` function already returns the value of the single input.
2. The `input` definition is quite simple in your case and does not contain any code  (just constants) -
   nothing to optimize in it. Look for a time consumers in other places.

Comment: yes, `input()` function is returning the string. But the GUI is not popping up and need to click build button in jenkins and click `Input requested` to get the GUI

Comment: if the job was triggered but requires user input - that's the behavior.

Comment: When I say clicking build button, I mean the red/green color button, after clicking `Build Now`

Comment: i guess you have a conditional input, so server requests it after some part of code has been executed

Comment: I want the input window to get popped up, when I click `Build Now`. Query edited

Comment: you have to provide your code also. because the problem in it.

Comment: as i told you, you have some code before input. that's why the build starts and later asks you for input.

Comment: Are you saying that, there is some code before input within stage view, so the choice window does not popup? I didn't get you

Comment: right. you have code before input `if`, `timeout` . just create a simple job with just input and it should work as you expect.

Comment: Why do you think, "if timeout" does not let input wizard to popup?

Comment: Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570163/jenkins-dynamic-declarative-pipeline-parameters/44626376#44626376

Answer (score 0):

Provide the "Choice Type" and "Referenced parameters" within Jenkins job to see the expected output. In your case Referenced parameters is "Env"