# How to display the selected parameter in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

There is a job groove pipeline that asks for parameters from the user interactively. After entering, I cannot display the selected parameters.
Here is my code:

```
node {
    stage('Input Stage') {
        Tag = sh(script: "echo 123'\n'456'\n'789'\n'111", returnStdout: true).trim()
        input(
            id: 'userInput', message: 'Choice values: ',
            parameters: [
                [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', name:'Tags', choices: "${Tag}"],
                [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'default', name:'Namespace'],
            ]
        )
    }
    stage('Second Stage') {
        println("${ChoiceParameterDefinition(Tags)}") //does not work
        println("${ChoiceParameterDefinition(Namespace)}") //does not work
    }
}
```

How to display the selected parameter correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write the input step in a script. This should work.

```
node {
    stage('Input Stage') {
        Tag = sh(script: "echo 123'\n'456'\n'789'\n'111", returnStdout: true).trim()
     script {
       def userInputs = 
       input(
              id: 'userInput', message: 'Choice values: ',
              parameters: [
                [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', name:'Tags', choices: "${Tag}"],
                [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'default', name:'Namespace'],
            ]
        )
      
      env.TAGS = userInputs['Tags']
      env.NAMESPACE = userInputs['Namespace'] 
     }
    }
    stage('Second Stage') {
        echo "${env.TAGS}"
        echo "${env.NAMESPACE}"        
        
    }
}
```

References:

[Jenkins Declarative Pipeline: How to read choice from input step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501553/jenkins-declarative-pipeline-how-to-read-choice-from-input-step)

[Read interactive input in Jenkins pipeline to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080683/read-interactive-input-in-jenkins-pipeline-to-a-variable)

Comment: It didn't work for me
```
echo "${env.userInputs['Tags']}"
echo "${env.userInputs['Namespace']}"
```
Error:
```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Tags for class: java.lang.String
Possible solutions: class
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you try for only Namespace?

Comment: Yes.
Error:
```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Namespace for class: java.lang.String
```

Comment: @LineeshAntony when using more then one parameter the returned value from the `input` step is a list and the environment (`env`) can contain only strings. Therefore a different parameter should be used.

Comment: @NoamHelmer Thanks for that! I have edited my code as per your suggestion

Comment: @Adnrey Please try with the changes and check if it works for you